# How to Determine if ::before is applied to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this simple html code. I need to be able to determine if the ::before is being applied to .icon-player-flash

```
    <div id="TestSwitch">

        <i class="icon-player-html5"></i>

        <i class="icon-player-none"></i>

        <i class="icon-player-flash"></i>

    </div>
```

[image]

I thought this would work but it's always returning 0 for the length.

```
var flashplayer = $(".icon-player-flash:before");
console.log("count: " + flashplayer.length);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot select elements with pseudo css tags, afaik

Comment: The bigger question though, is if you have a rule defined for it, why do you think it would not be applied to it?

Comment: ok, if I use $(".icon-player-flash"); then how can I determine if ::before is being applied to it?

Comment: Again, why would it not be applied to it?  You're not explaining what the issue is.  You're only asking about your issue with a solution you tried.  This is by definition the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm trying to determine when it's being applied. If it's not applied then that option isn't selected. Before you argue on the best practices, it's not my code and that's what I have to work with.

Comment: The ::before will be applied if the element matches the rule.  You should know what criteria defines the ::before rule.  Given that, you should be able to test if the element matches that rule, and if it does, the ::before would be applied to it.  Example being if your css rule is `.icon-player-flash::before {}` then all you have to do is test if the element has the class of `icon-player-flash`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getComputedStyle` and check the value of `content`. If it's `none` then the pseudo element isn't defined:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".box");
var c = window.getComputedStyle(elem,"before").getPropertyValue("content");
console.log(c);

var elem = document.querySelector(".alt");
var c = window.getComputedStyle(elem,"before").getPropertyValue("content");
console.log(c);
```

```css
.box:before {
  content:"I am defined"
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="alt"></div>
```

> This property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements to generate content in a document. Values have the following meanings:
>
> none
>
> The pseudo-element **is not generated**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#content)</sup>

If you want to count simply consider a filter:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const divs = [...elems].filter(e => {
   var c = window.getComputedStyle(e,"before").getPropertyValue("content");
  return c != "none"
});

console.log(divs.length)
```

```css
.box:before {
  content:"I am defined"
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box alt"></div>

<div class="alt"></div>
<div ></div>
```

Comment: `$(this).get(0);` <= is effectively the same as `1 + 1 - 1`.  You're wrapping the element, and then unwrapping it.