# How to check if an element has a :before pseudo-element using only scss

Tags: css

I would like to style the div element only if section has :before pseudo.

```
<section>
  <div>something</div>
</section>
```

Something like this:

```
section:has(:before) {
 div {
   background-color: grey;
 }
}
```

Comment: it can be done with only JS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58001666/8620333

Comment: This is a workaround: you can change whatever css attribute you want to a :before pseudoclass, since those who don't have a :before with the attribute content set wont be affected. So section:before {background:red;} will affect only those with :before and the attribute content:""; even if it's empty.