# How do I extract tags with ::marker from HTML using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find li elements that have ::marker such as seen below using BeautifulSoup.

I tried using cssutils but was unsuccessful (maybe I am using it wrong)

[image]

Pseudo code:

```
lis = soup_obj.find_all("li")
for li in lis:
  if li (has :: marker): # This is what I would like to do 
     print(li)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there an actual url to go with this? Also, please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert actual html rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you won't be able to use cssutils as the pseudo element `::marker` is not supported syntax. According to https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/README.html#overview
under

> [Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
>
> The selector syntax defined here (and not in CSS 2.1) should be
> parsable with cssutils (should mind though ;) )

You see supported should be (in section 7):

```
7.1.The ::first-line pseudo-element
7.2.The ::first-letter pseudo-element
7.4.The ::before and ::after pseudo-elements
```

Additionally, [no pseudo elements are supported by Soup Sieve](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/):

> Soup Sieve aims to allow users to target XML/HTML elements with CSS
> selectors. It implements many pseudo classes, but it does not
> currently implement any pseudo elements and has no plans to do so.

Perhaps relevant is whether you can try using JavaScript via Selenium automation. Discussions of note are comments here:

[How to select and manipulate specific <li> elements present with pseudo-elements such as ::marker, ::before using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592980/how-to-select-and-manipulate-specific-li-elements-present-with-pseudo-elements#comment-119500381). Though that discussion is about `getComputedStyle` which is different from your end goal.

---

An example page, if others want to have a play, are the bottom bullets in this page:

`https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/next-level-list-bullets-with-css-marker--cms-37212`

For as long as that link remains live.

---

It could be there is another pattern you could use to target the desired nodes. It would help therefore, to share the link if public and freely accesible.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest work-around that I have found was to use:

```
list(li.stripped_strings)[-1]
```

Comment: How is this finding only `li` with pseudo element `::marker`? If there is an working example you should provide it.